# It is possible to update a value in loop

Tags: python, tornado

I`m trying to update a value into a infinite loop, without exiting the loop. This value is send as parameter from a WebSocket client. My question is: how can I update a value which is inside of infinit loop?

```
class WebSocketHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def open(self):
        print('new connection')
        clients.append(self)
        self.write_message("connected")
    def on_message(self, message): 
        print('tornado received from client: %s' % message) 
        new_message ="" 
        while True: 
            new_message=self.updateMessage(message) 
            print(new_message) 

    def updateMessage(self, message): 
        return(message)

def main():
    parse_command_line()
    app = tornado.web.Application(
        [
            (r"/ws", WebSocketHandler)
        ],
    template_path=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "templates"),
    static_path=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "static")
    )
    app.listen(options.port)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I want that printed message inside of loop to update with the new message, which is received in on_message function. If I remove the while loop, will be printed the new message (the new value sent by Websocket client). But now it is printed only the first message(value) forever, because the loop.

Comment: I think it would be nice to distill your code down into a simple example that captures the essence of your question, which sounds like a basic python question. It's more general that way (i.e. helpful to future readers), and no need for us to parse lots of WebSocket code.

Comment: Your indentation is broken. Since indentation is **syntactically important** in python, it's no use discussing this until you fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Tornado listens to messages and executes "on_message" each time a new message is received. So you execute the endless loop *for every message you get* which is not what you want.

Secondly I think that tornado uses a single process and thread by default, so if you block it with an endless loop it cannot receive further messages.

Instead you should run some asyncronous code. You can read more in the tornado documentatio or the python asyncio documentation, but the following should work:

```
class WebSocketHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):

    newest_message = None

    def open(self):
        print('new connection')
        clients.append(self)
        self.write_message("connected")

    def on_message(self, message): 
        print('tornado received from client: %s' % message)
        self.newest_message = message
        asyncio.ensure_future(show_newest_message())

    async def show_newest_message(self):
        if self.newest_message is not None:
            while True:
                print(self.newest_message)
                asyncio.sleep(1)
```

I'm not that familiar with the tornado and the asyncio libraries, so there might be better ways to do what you want to do.

Comment: unfortunately, is not working...Will be printing the same value. When I send new value, it won't changing in loop.

Comment: Show the code which produces the wrong results. In the code in your question nothing is changed.

Comment: def on_message(self, message):
        print('tornado received from client: %s' % message)
        new_message =""
        while True:
            new_message=self.updateMessage(message)
            print(new_message)

    def updateMessage( self,message):
        return(message)

Comment: Your `updateMessage` doesn't do anything besides simply returning the message. How should it be modified? Also please edit your original question with that code so that it is more readable.

Comment: You need to modify the string in the way you want. E.g. `message = message + "a"` or whatever you want. What exactly do you want?

Comment: @B.S I updated my answer to hopefully answer your actual question. I'm not that familiar with tornado or asyncio, so if there is sill something not working you might want to open a new question with more information upfront. Asyncronous libraries do change much so  be sure to bring up if you use one in future questions.

Comment: thank you very much for your efforts. I was trying the code with async but I became "invalid error syntax at async def ". I`m stuck here, I was looking to solve this error but no success.

Comment: Finally I got it, it`s working as I want. I use your helpfully comments and I got it. I use for my "show_newest_message" function @gen.coroutine and in my loop yield gen.moment. I could use yield gen.sleep() but I think this will be best for my needs. I voted your advise.